# Holiday cooking: website(s) with prepared menus?

Tags: food, product-recommendation, internet, cooking-bishul, chagim-holidays

There are plenty of websites with endless recipes for appetizers, desserts, etc. but they don't help you coordinate between the different parts of the meal, suggesting which salads go with which soups, etc. I'm looking for a website that takes it up a notch -- featuring full kosher menus appropriate for shabbat and holiday meals, preferably including the recipes for the constituent parts of the meal. Any suggestions? (I'm asking this question under the clause 'Jewish life' as per [Lists of in- and out-of-scope topics for the FAQ](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/178/lists-of-in-and-out-of-scope-topics-for-the-faq/196#196) . Please remove if it's nevertheless off-topic).

Comment: Not a website, but *[Kosher by Design](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/kbdh.html)* has holiday menus.

Comment: @IsaacMoses ...as do many other cookbooks.